# In how many tables, product custom attribute entries saved?

Tags: database, magento2.2, product-attribute, sql, foreign-key

Suppose I have a product custom attribute 'brand', **after choosing one of the brand options & saving the product in how many tables this product attribute will be saved?**

attribute "brand" type is varchar so according to me it'll be saved in the "catalog_product_entity_varchar" table.

But when I'm inserting values directly into this table by using insert query.

**e.g-**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
(NULL, 611, 0, 11, '560');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**Then getting following problem:-**

Error
SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
(NULL, 611, 0, 11, '560')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dev21_wp2`.`catalog_product_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE )
```

Please clarify me & help me to resolve this issue.